# How to move object

Tags: ipad

i am working on a project in which i have to provide user facility to draw an circle . i have done this part. But new requirement is that user can move it at any his desire position.I have no idea about it.please help me.

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific.

Comment: i just want to perform two task
1.) Draw an circle(so that user can crop an image in circled form).
2.) Allow user to move Circle.

Answer (score 0):

Make a subview of UIView. In it, override drawRect: to draw your circle. Add it to a superview that is the size of the screen. Then, give your view a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Set the target/action to a method on your circle view, and in that method set the view's frame to have an origin at the gesture recogniser's locationInView:.

If you need more specific help than this, feel free to post some code that you're having trouble with.